# C# RealProxy: for chained methods not working logging (Fluent interface pattern)

Tags: c#, realproxy

Why not working logging for chained methods, but if the same methods call via the saved instance, logging for ones work fine

[Gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/rmarinsky/8cccc2ec0f0415afd3b9f47420290a07)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, It's happened instead of that each method returned `this` but not Tranparet Proxy class Calculator
So need to change at Calculator's methods `this` to

`return (Calculator)new StepProxy<Calculator>(this).GetTransparentProxy();`